# Using Try: and Finally: to delete an existing file and write the new output to the file

Tags: python-2.7, try-finally

I was trying to check and delete an existing output file, and write on a new file. However, my code didn't seem to work because it only captures the output from the last iteration.

```
# delete inactive contracts from dict()
for key, item in contracts.items():
    if item['contract_status'] == 'Inactive':
        del contracts[key]
    else:
        if os.path.exists(main_path):
            try:
                os.remove(main_path)
            finally:
                outfile = open(main_path, 'a')
                outfile.write(item['name'])
                outfile.write('\n')
            outfile.close()
```

Comment: Does your last line really have that indent level?

Comment: Note that using `try:` `finally:` here makes no sense. You want to write the file then have the exception handled at a higher level? Also, why not include `outfile.close()` in the `finally` suite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing the file, just open it for writing:

```
else:
    with open(main_path, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(item['name'])
        outfile.write('\n')
```

Opening a file with `w` truncates the file first, so data written to it replaces the old contents. Note that you are writing the file for *each* iteration in the loop.

By using the file as a context manager (`with ..`) it's closed automatically.

If you want to write all entries to the file, open the file *outside* of the loop:

```
with open(main_path, 'w') as outfile:
    for key, item in contracts.items():
        if item['contract_status'] == 'Inactive':
            del contracts[key]
        else:
            outfile.write(item['name'])
            outfile.write('\n')
```

If you need to re-write the file *only* if there are no inactive items in `contracts`, use:

```
contracts = {k: v for k, v in contracts.iteritems() if v['contract_status'] != 'Inactive'}
if contracts:
    with open(main_path, 'w') as outfile:
        for contract in contracts.values():
            outfile.write(item['name'])
            outfile.write('\n')
```

Now you first remove the inactive items, then if there are still contracts left, write those out to the file. If there are none left, the `main_path` file is left untouched.

Comment: I tried your code, but the result is still the same. The output only captures the last line. Very strange!

Comment: @TingPing: Not surprising, since you re-open the file for each iteration of the loop. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
outfile = open(main_path, 'w') # this truncates existing file if any

# delete inactive contracts from dict()
for key, item in contracts.items():
    if item['contract_status'] == 'Inactive':
        del contracts[key]
    else:
        outfile.write(item['name'])
        outfile.write('\n')

outfile.close()
```

should it be rewritten into such a like one?